Skew spot relationship
How does skew : (25D Put Iv - 25D Call Iv)/50D Iv change with spot? Is there a well defined relationship? And why?
E.g does falling spot increase or decrease skew? How is that change is skew different across expiries (weeklies vs monthlies vs 3 monthlies) etc.

My 2 cents..no. there is no well defined relationship. It depends on the mkt, the underlying and the circumstance. Each mkt has its own heuristic approaches to what 'should' happen, these are also disproved from time to time.

From What Does Implied Volatility Skew Measure? - Mixon (2011), it seems that the skew measure you are referring to is inversely related to the spot price (S&P 500 in this case). Take note that the skew measure in Mixon is continuous 30 days TTM (similar to the VIX).
See the figure below for a comparison between Figure 1 in Mixon (2011) and the VIX by CBOE for the duration of Jan 2005 to Jan 2010, which proves that both show a similar pattern and are thus inversely related to the spot (since VIX is well-known to be inverse to the S&P 500 and is used as a hedge for systematic risk ).
You can see that they both spike around the same time below.


